# ‘No such file or directory - pandoc’ when trying to use :markdown filter in haml-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, markdown, haml, pandoc

I am trying to use the [`:markdown`](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#markdown-filter) filter with [`haml-rails`](https://github.com/indirect/haml-rails) on Rails 5.0.2.

When I first tried to use Markdown in a HAML file, it said it needed `pandoc-ruby` as a dependency, so I added that to my Gemfile. However, now when I try to use `:markdown` inside my file, I am getting the following error:

[image: Screenshot of error]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don’t need Pandoc here, that’s just the first markdown processor Tilt tries to use and reports if it can’t find any others. You do need some markdown processor though.

Your simplest fix would probably be to remove `pandoc-ruby` from your `Gemfile` and add a Ruby markdown processor (e.g. [`kramdown`](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/)).

If you need more control over which processor Haml uses (e.g. if you want to use kramdown for Haml filters but have RedCarpet in your app for something else), try something like this in an initializer:

```ruby
require 'tilt/kramdown'
module Haml::Filters
  remove_filter("Markdown")
  register_tilt_filter "Markdown", :template_class => Tilt::KramdownTemplate
end
```

If you do want to use Pandoc for rendering markdown then you need to make sure it’s installed, see [Chris’ answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43484506/214790).

Answer (score 2):

From [its README](https://github.com/alphabetum/pandoc-ruby):

> PandocRuby is a wrapper for [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/), a Haskell library with command line tools for converting one markup format to another.

It requires Pandoc to be installed separately (emphasis added):

> ***First, make sure to [install Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/installing.html).***
>
> Next, add PandocRuby to your Gemfile
>
> ```
> gem 'pandoc-ruby'
> ```

Comment: I'm not sure why this earned a downvote. Matt's solution is better, but installing Pandoc should fix the error the OP was seeing with PandocRuby.

Comment: In my question I said: “it said it needed pandoc-ruby as a dependency, so I added that to my Gemfile”

Comment: @BenjaminHumphrey, installing PandocRuby is not enough. As noted above, you also need to install Pandoc itself: "First, make sure to install Pandoc". The error you are seeing, "No such file or directory - pandoc", means RubyPandoc can't find the `pandoc` program.